# Changing the property file value using magnolia cms

Tags: content-management-system, magnolia

Hi We are using magnolia as cms. To support multiple language we use different i18 property files. But to changes these files, code changes are required.
**Do magnolia provides a way so we can change the property files without the code change?**

Comment: What do you mean by code changes? What you need to change exactly?

Comment: @Ducaz035 I need to change property files. Currently to do this we change the code and push to master then whole build process is done. So I am just looking that If magnolia provides a way to change the property file though any UI console from magnolia dashboard..so that I dont need to start server again and again

Answer (score 2):

Magnolia offers you to 'hotfix' any file which comes from classpath or file system via Resource Files App. If one tries to edit a file, Magnolia creates a hotfix of it and stores it in JCR. Which has priority in the system and your changes will be picked up from there automatically.

For more information, please have a look at:
https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS60/Resource+Files+app

HTH,

Cheers,